# Setting section header height and row height to 0

Tags: ios, uitableview

I don't have now access to XCode to check my question, but I would like to know if it is possible  the following scenario: A UITableView with sections, in some app situations I don't want to show a section (e.g section 0), but I need the section 0 rows to be taken into account to the rest of the tableView.

My question is, would there be problems with indexes, expected number of sections and/or expected number of rows, fetchedResultsController, etc., if I hide section 0 and its rows setting their heights to 0?

Thank you

Comment: Nothing will happen it will work fine

Comment: @CharanGiri, thank you for your comment. If you are sure about it, please put your comment into an answer. I would be very glad to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing will happen it will work fine. Because, we can hide a section or view what ever we  need in tableview we have an advantage of showing no.of rows and no.of sections. Here we are hiding  section0 by providing its height as 0 and at the same time if we want to hide its row also(rows of  section 0) then we need to set height for row in section0 as 0.

Answer (score 1):

I did that yesterday.

I used the following deleguate:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
            heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

and I returned `0` like you said. It works perfect

Comment: Thank you, but the first comment was from @CharanGiri. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Thats okay  i was just sharing my experience!